# Searching option in google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i have successfully displayed google map in my app . but i am not able to search the specfied location . can u please put the code snippet or any link available for the  code .

Answer (score 0):

To get a location (latitude and longitude) from a location name(e.g. "paris" or "japan"), use Geocoder.getFromLocationName()

To display a specific latitude/longitude on the map use MapControl.setCenter()

Comment: the user has to enter a place name in the search box and the map has to display that place .. how can i do this? plz help me